# Did God abandon Jesus? Why?

Tags: matthew, jesus

> “And about the ninth hour Jesus cried out with a loud voice, saying, “Eli, Eli, lema sabachthani?” that is, “My God, my God, why have you forsaken me?””
> ‭‭Matthew‬ ‭27:46‬ ‭